# Sharepoint 2010 Nested If Limit

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, calculated-column-formula

In SharePoint 2007 the limit for the number of nested IF statements was 7. On the 8th SharePoint would return and error.

On my 2010 site I made an error and added 8 nested IF statements and there was no error. I started doing some testing and the limit now seems to be 19. I searched on the web and I couldn't find any documentation that states when this changed. My assumption is with service pack 2.

I was wondering if anyone knows when this change happened and are there any other limitiations that have been changed? I have been operating under the 7 rule so some of my lists need multiple calculated fields - this helps a lot.